# How to Link to specific route in react dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, url-routing

```
<Route path="/dashboard" component={dashboard} >
  <Route path='/home' component={Home} /> 
  <IndexRoute  component={Myplan} />
  <Route path='/myprofile' component={MyProfile} />
  <Route path='/users' component={Users} />
  <Route path='/notifications' component={Notifications} />
  <Route path='/reports' component={Report} />
</Route>
```

In the routes.js file i am using IndexRoute to Myplan component In the entire Dashboard Component so when login It is redirecting to the Myplan component only

In the Dashboard Component

In the render Method I am rendering the components like this

```
{
validate!= 0 ? <li><Link to="/home" > Home <i className="fa fa-home"></i></Link></li> : null
}

{
validate!= 0 ? <li><Link to="/reports"> Analytics <i className="fa fa-line-chart"></i></Link></li> : null
}

<li><Link to="/dashboard"> My Plan <i className="fa fa-ticket"></i></Link></li>
<li><Link to="/myprofile" onClick={() => this.handleEdit(edituser.user)}> My Profile <i className="fa fa-ticket"></i></Link></li>
```

I Need the The Home component to be linked when the "validate!= 0"
In the render i am checking like this, What is the right way to do dynamic routing based on condition check.

```
if(validate!= 0){
  return <Link to="/home" />
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple Conditional Routing in Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497510/simple-conditional-routing-in-reactjs)

Comment: My question is different!