# Why is this.props undefined in conditional routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

I am trying to create a conditional route by creating a `ProtectedRoute` component as described by the chosen answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497510/simple-conditional-routing-in-reactjs).

The condition comes from the props passed into the `ProtectedRoute` component. Please have a look at the component and routing code below.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';

class ProtectedRoute extends Component {
    render() {
      const { component: Component, ...props } = this.props
  
      return (
        <Route 
          {...props} 
          render={props => (
            this.props.profile.name === "admin" ?
              <Component {...props} /> :
              <Redirect to='/login' />
          )} 
        />
      )
    }
  }
export default ProtectedRoute;
```

The following is how I achieve the routing in a separate side navigation bar component. The `profile` object is passed as props to this component from `App.js`.

```
<main>
      <Route path="/" exact component={props => <Home/>} />
      <ProtectedRoute path="/dashboard" component={props => <Dashboard profile={this.props.profile} />} />
</main>
```

The error I am getting when running the above application is: `TypeError: _this2.props.pofile is undefined`. However, when I put a `Route` instead of `ProtectedRoute` i.e.
`<Route path="/dashboard" component={props => <Dashboard profile={this.props.profile} />} />`,
the application works as expected.

Could someone please assist me by pointing out what I am doing wrong? That would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why `_this2.props.pofile is undefined` - you haven't passed it to `ProtectedRoute` component, however, you passed it to `Dashboard`.

The right way to pass it is:

```
<ProtectedRoute path="/dashboard" profile={this.props.profile} component={props => <Dashboard profile={this.props.profile} />} />
```

By the way, it is not the best practice to pass JSX as a prop, better to pass it as children:

```
<ProtectedRoute path="/dashboard" profile={this.props.profile}>
  <Dashboard profile={this.props.profile} />
</ProtectedRoute>
```

and then inside of `ProtectedRoute` just render `{this.props.children}`.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `Route`'s `render` property you use an arrow function which means that context inside it is bound to `ProtectedRoute`'s instance. `this.props` inside `render` resolve to props of `ProtectedRoute` in other words. To solve this issue you need to pass `profile`  to `ProtectedRoute` instead of `Dashboard`:

```
<main>
  <Route path="/" exact component={props => <Home/>} />
  <ProtectedRoute path="/dashboard" profile={this.props.profile} component={props => <Dashboard />} />
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

On this error `TypeError: _this2.props.pofile is undefined` it's `pofile` and not `profile`

Some where you define the wrong typo maybe.