# React, how to properly handle success pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

How to properly handle success page behaviors?

After Sign Up, I have to show a Sign Up Success page.

What I've tried so far:

**1. The same route for the SignUp Form and SignUp Success Page so if they enter the `/sign-up` route, `Sign Up` form will show up.**

In my SignUp Component, the view is dependent on the sign up status,

```
if signUp === success render Success Page
else render Sign Up Form
```

The problem with this is that there is a `Sign Up` button in the header on the same page and if I click that, it remains in the `success view` since the sign up and success shares one route.

```
<Button onClick={this.navigateToSignUp} />
```

**2. Made another route for SignUp Success Page**

I made a separate route for sign up success page (**/sign-up-success**) but I don't want the users to be able to manually access the route since it should only show after a successful registration.

Comment: A simple solution would be to add a `flag` after the user has registered. Or maybe you have a way to verify that. And check that flag, if true let user remain on page, if not, redirect. Or  just use conditional routing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497510/simple-conditional-routing-in-reactjs . There are many solutions. Try one and come back if it doesn't work and show us what you've tried

Comment: You will need to pass any flag through its action trigger/parent page through code. Dont pass any flag thr url.

Comment: It sounds like the route does need authentication. You can protect a route through this pattern https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

Comment: @Robert I edited my post to make my question clearer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want give page to load through script and not through link itself. Try below hack.
You can easily pass state through link or history.push() . So pass some boolean value through the state and use that state value to verify whether the link is loaded through manually(through input,no state) or automatically(redirection by you code,yes state).

```
this.props.location.state
```

gives the passed state object in your success page