# React Redirect if this.props.location.state is null

Tags: reactjs, router

I set a Component state with data from `this.props.location.state`. How can I redirect if it's null.

My Application has 2 routes:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
       <Route path="/comp2" component={Comp2} />
       <Route path="/" exact component={Comp1} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

From Comp1 I can go to Comp2.

```
<Link to={{ pathname: "/comp2", state: {values} }}>{values.description}</Link>
```

Then, I set my state in the Comp2 with this data:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: this.props.location.state.values
    };
}
```

It's working. However, if in the browser, I go straight to http://localhost:3000/comp2, it fails. How can I redirect back to http://localhost:3000 if the `this.props.location.state.values` is null?

Thanks

Comment: why does it fail ? maybe adding a default value if your states value don't exist like ```data: this.props.location.state.values || [] ```

Comment: Might be a duplicate question. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497510/simple-conditional-routing-in-reactjs

Comment: @MarcCharpentier Because values is undefined

Comment: @jtabuloc No, it's different. Thanks

Comment: and if you add a default value like I did above ?

Comment: @MarcCharpentier I did what you did and it still returning ```Cannot read property 'values' of undefined``` in the constructor

Comment: I also, would like to go back to the home page if it's undefined

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

const data = this.props.location.state
? history.location.state.values : ''

in return (

```
<>
{data ? 
       <div> //ur comp2 component dom </div>
       : 
       <Redirect to="/homePage" />
}
</>
)
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand it. Where should I add this return?

Comment: comp2  component

Comment: What's Redirect? From where it's coming from?

Comment: ask a new question on stackoverflow for this,, instead of asking questions go through react official documentation and then start coding