# Prevent user from going to profile page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

So I need to prevent the user from going back to the profile page (/profile) after he already selected a profile.
I'm storing the profile selected inside the application state.

Scenario wanted: User goes to /profile, select a profile, then goes to '/' (which is my home), and can navigate to /exams if he wants.
BUT, he can't go back to /profile, since he's already inside the application with a profile stored in the state. If he tries to go to /profile, through browser back-arrow or even typing /profile in the url, the current page simply reloads.

What's the best way to achieve this?

OBS: this **const { id } = useSelector...** is the const that retrieves the profile from the state, so I have to use this as condition, but I don't know how.

Therefore, if the user have an id that's not empty (which means he already selected a profile), he can't go back to profile. Other than that, he can visit /profile.

Below follows my route.tsx :

```
const Exams = lazy(() => import('../pages/private/Exams'));
const Home = lazy(() => import('../pages/private/Home'));
const ProfileSelector = lazy(() => import('../pages/private/ProfileSelector'));
const { id } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.profile);

const AppRoutes = () => {
    return (
        <Router history={history}>
            <Suspense fallback={<LoadingPage />}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path={'/'} component={Home} />
                    <Route exact path={'/exams'} component={Exams} />
                    <Route exact path={'/profile'} component={ProfileSelector} />
                </Switch>
            </Suspense>
        </Router>
    );
};

export default AppRoutes;
```

My profile store if there's any use:

```
    interface UserProfileModel {
    id: string;
    council: string;
    state: string;
    number: string;
    description: string;
}

const initialState: UserProfileModel = {
    id: '',
    council: '',
    state: '',
    number: '',
    description: '',
};

export const userProfileSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'profile',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        selectProfile: (state, action: PayloadAction<UserProfileModel>) => {
            return {
                ...state,
                ...action.payload,
            };
        },
        clearProfile: () => initialState,
    },
});

export const { selectProfile, clearProfile } = userProfileSlice.actions;

export default userProfileSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple Conditional Routing in Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497510/simple-conditional-routing-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a state for example profileSelected to true when the user selects a profile then:

put

```
{profileSelected ? null : <Route exact path={'/profile'} component={ProfileSelector} />}
```

instead of

```
<Route exact path={'/profile'} component={ProfileSelector} />
```